# Android mvvm - does every crud operation should have it own ViewModel?

Tags: java, android, mvvm

Does every CRUD operation should have own ViewModel? For example, should I have separated classes for Insert,Delete,Update?

Comment: I think there is no need for that, create a repository and do all the operations there, and better if you do CRUD operation in a thread

Comment: Of course, each action needs to own DTO/VM. Models should never be sent as a result or shouldn't be used directly.

Comment: disagree with @SaeidAmini and i agree with abdul, which means this question is too opinion-based

Comment: @a_local_nobody I sent my comment as Backend-side(Java). If you talking about Client-side(Android), yes, your right. You just need a model and map API result to your model.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a Data Access Object (DAO) for every Entity. There is no need for separate ViewModels for every CRUD operations.

One or multiple ViewModels can then use this DAO as needed. Look at this [DAO](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/architecture/blueprints/todoapp/data/source/local/TasksDao.kt) for a reference. See how this [repository](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/architecture/blueprints/todoapp/data/source/TasksRepository.kt) and [viewmodel](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/architecture/blueprints/todoapp/statistics/StatisticsViewModel.kt) work with it.